# How to get the primary menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a weird menu in wordpress. I'm studying to create my own theme. But now I stack here in menu. see this [image]

I cannot see the checkbox of primary menu, under menu settings. If I change theme. I can see the checkbox. but I already copy all codes. look at my code

```
function hello_header_menu() {
  // display the WordPress Custom Menu if available
  wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu'              => 'primary',
    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
    'depth'             => 2,
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_class'   => '',
    'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav nav',
    'fallback_cb'       => 'hello_wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'            => new  hello_wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
  ));
} /* end header menu */
endif;
```

I wonder why I get this weird issue.

Comment: read about menu location , I think that will help you.

Comment: Beside this I would also like to suggest you underscores stater theme, that is great to learn theme development .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Use register_nav_menu, see code below:

```
<?php

function xyz_menu_option() {

    register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu');
    register_nav_menu('secondary','Secondary Menu');

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'xyz_menu_option');

?>
```

You can go ahead to add as many menu options as needed, just repeat the code below using the title for the option of your choice:

```
register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu');
```

I hope this is helpful. I'm just a learner like you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you won't declare emplacement for the menu. test this in functions

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_template_setup' ) ) :

function my_template_setup() {

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'my_template_language' )
    ) );

}
endif; 
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_template_setup' );
```